# Exercises with Dirac notation

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Let $Q$ be an operator and $|f\rangle$ a vector in a complex Hilbert space H.

> How do I prove that
>   1. If $\langle f|Q|f\rangle=0$ for every $|f\rangle$ in H, then $Q$ is zero;
>   2. $Q$ is hermitian iff $\langle f|Q|f\rangle\in \mathbb{R}$ for every $|f\rangle$ in H?

1 Let's write $|f\rangle$ as $\sum_i a_i|e_i\rangle$. Then $\langle f|Q|f\rangle=\sum_j a_j\langle e_i|Q\sum_i a_i|e_i\rangle=\sum_j\sum_i a_ja_i\langle e_j|Q|e_i\rangle=0$, so $\langle e_j|Q|e_i\rangle=0$ for all $i,j$. Does this immediateluy imply that $Q=0$?

2 If $Q$ is hermitian, then $Q^\dagger=Q$. This means that $\langle f|Q|f\rangle=\langle Q^\dagger f|f\rangle$  How do I continue from here? If $|f\rangle$ were an eigenvector it would be easy, but the statement must hold for all $|f\rangle$.

If $\langle f|Q|f\rangle\in \mathbb{R}$, I am supposed to use 1. but I don't see how.

Comment: The first statement is false as it is currently stated; you're missing pieces from the original question.  Do we know something special about $Q$?  Is it self-adjoint, positive definite perhaps?   Is the statement saying that $\langle f|Q|f\rangle=0$ for a particular vector $|f\rangle$, or is it saying that this holds for *all* $|f\rangle$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It holds for all $|f\rangle$, at the beginning I took a random vector and it is stated again in the comment for 2.

Comment: All I understand from your comment is "it holds for all $|f \rangle$", but I suppose that's enough

Comment: Your statements have a hope of being correct if you add in the condition "for all $|f \rangle \in H$" where $H$ is a complex Hilbert space. Otherwise they are blatantly false.

Comment: @Ian not all Hilbert spaces are $\Bbb C^n$.  But yes, it seems that's what he meant.

Comment: @Ian thats what I meant yes, sorry for the omission

Comment: Regarding $\langle e_i | Q | e_j\rangle=0$, think about the case of $Q$ a finite-dimensional matrix. In that case, this amounts to saying that each element of $Q$ is zero. But that's the _definition_ of a zero matrix.

Comment: @Semiclassical That doesn't help because you have to have the left side and the right side being the same. In other words you have $|f \rangle$ orthogonal to $Q|f \rangle$ for all $|f \rangle$.

Comment: @Ian what do you mean by left and right side?

Comment: The thing multiplying $Q$ on the left and the right are the same (or rather are adjoints).

Comment: @Ian I'm referring to what he showed in his work on part (1).

Comment: Ah, that wasn't there when I was reading the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint for 1:** One approach is to use the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity).  Another approach is to consider the expressions
$$
\langle f+g | Q | f+g \rangle , \qquad 
\langle f+ig | Q | f+ig \rangle
$$

Whichever way you approach the problem, it is helpful to note that if $\langle f | Q |g\rangle$ for every combination of vectors $|f\rangle,|g\rangle$, then $Q$ is necessarily $0$.

**Hint for 2:**  The actual statement (which you seem to have copied incorrectly) is as follows:

> $Q$ is Hermitian iff for every $|f \rangle \in H$, we have $\langle f|Q|f\rangle \in \Bbb R$.

If $Q$ is Hermitian, it suffices to note that for *any* $Q$, we have
$$
[\langle f | Q|f \rangle]^* = [\langle f | Q|f \rangle]^\dagger = \langle f|Q^\dagger |f \rangle
$$
where $^*$ denotes the complex conjugate.  For the other direction: if $\langle f |Q |f\rangle \in \Bbb R$ for all $|f \rangle$, what can you say about
$\langle f | (Q - Q^\dagger)|f \rangle$?

Comment: $\langle f|(Q-Q^\dagger)|f\rangle$ is zero?

Comment: That's right; and from there you can use the first part.